# How to make the platform independent filepath slash "/" with GLib? (GJS)

Tags: gtk, gtk3, glib, gjs

I have a `folderPath` which has a directory string:

```
/home/bastian/Pictures
```

and I have a variable `fileName` which contains the name.
I can concatenate the two strings together like this, but it only works on UNIX systems:

```
let filePath = folderPath + '/' + fileName;
```

Is there a way with GLib I can concatenate the two to each other without making assumptions about the slash or backslash (to stay fx Windows-compatible)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With help from guadec, I found out I could use GLib's [g_build_filenamev ()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-build-filenamev) function.

```
let filePath = GLib.build_filenamev([folderPath, fileName]);
```

This builds a path to the file and respects the platform at the same time.

Note: it requires that you import GLib first at the top of your GJS file, like this:

```
const { GLib } = imports.gi;
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer, it's allowed and [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Functions that end with a v manipulate a vector. If you want a defined path not provided in an array (which is your example), then  [g_build_filename](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-build-filename) is more natural. If you want some control on the separator, you can use [g_build_path](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions.html#g-build-path) with `G_DIR_SEPARATOR_S` which adapts to the platform. For example if you want to force forward-slashes separated paths on Windows (which should work too).

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to be using a `Gio.File` object to manipulate the path, you can also do something like this:

```
const folder = Gio.File.new_for_path(folderPath);
const file = folder.get_child(fileName);
```